# How can I redirect to another page after verifying username and password with webforms .Net 4.7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vuejs2, webforms

I'm using Vuejs2 with Asp.Net / WebForms 4.7 and I'm passing the data to C# with JSON/Ajax to validate in firebird. How can I make the redirect to the main page after validation?

## CSharp Code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string User_Login(User p_User)
    {
        try
        {
            User user = new User();

            if (user.Password == p_User.Password && user.Users == p_User.Users)
            {
                user.Users = p_User.Users;
                user.Password = p_User.Password;
                user.Abrir(); //Abrir = Open (open data in database)

            }

            return "";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

## Vuejs2 Code

```
login: function () {

                    var _this = this;

                    var data = {
                        p_User: {
                            Users: _this.form.user,
                            Password: _this.form.password
                        }
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'Login.aspx/User_Login',
                        async: true,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        beforeSend: function () { },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert("recebido")
                        },
                        //complete: function () {

                        //}
                    });
                },
```

Comment: `throw new Exception(error.Message.ToString(), error);` <-- This is **not** how to re-throw exceptions - just use `throw;` by itself.

Comment: ok, i made this.

Comment: Add return type in web method like login success or fail and check this status in ajax call. like if status == success then redirect to page.